# Trying to test a function that has a partial function that is wrapped with a Try and Either

Tags: scala

I have a function that's signature looks like:

```
def processUsers(user: User): PartialFunction[Try[Either[Boolean, User]], Int] = {
  case Success(s) =>
  case Failure(f) =>

}
```

Now in my scala test I have this so far:

```
whenReady(userService.processUsers(testUser)) {

}
```

I'm not sure how to pass in a partial function that I can simulate both the sucess and failure paths.

Comment: Just curious: Why does `processUsers()` return a _partial_ function? It looks like both `Success()` and `Failure()` are covered so when will `.isDefinedAt()` return **false**?

Comment: Also, what does `whenReady` have to do with this? It is supposed to take a `Future`, not a `PartialFunction`. As to how to simulate success and failure, you just pass them into the function. `processUsers(foo)(Success(Left(true)))` or  `processUsers(foo)(Success(Right(foo))` or `processUsers(foo)(Failure(new Exception("badness")))`

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot going on here.  The semantics of the method are a little confusing, it's called `processUsers` (plural) but takes a single user object.  Also, the method returns a partial function, but the implementation looks like it's operating on the return value, e.g. there's nothing to match `Success` or `Failure` against in the method body.

Maybe, you want your `processUsers` function to have a multi-parameter list that accepts a function parameter?

Something like

```
def processUsers(user: User)(op: user => Either[Boolean, User]): Try[Either[Boolean, User]]] = {
  Try {
    // pre-processing that may cause an exception
    op(user)
  }
}
```

Then you could write a test case like so

```
  processUsers(user) { user => /* do stuff */ } match {
    case Success(Left(false)) => ???
    case Success(Left(true)) => ???
    ...
  }
```

I'm not sure if this is what you are going for. I wouldn't advocate this approach but maybe it answers your question.